# bibtex DOI/URL in Helvetica font

Tags: fonts, bibtex, doi, times, helvetica

Bibtex seems to force Times font style for DOI numbers, against my font style Helvetica.

Please consult:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{foo2010,
  author = "Foo Bar",
  journal = "J.P.B.",
  year = 2010,
  title = "Where the wild things are.",
  doi = {10.1.1/jpb001},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1.1/jpb001}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}

\usepackage{helvet}  % helvetica font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sfmath}  % helvetica for math mode too

\begin{document}
test \citet{foo2010}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`natbib` in the presence of `hyperref` uses the `url` package to format these and that package defines a sans serif style which you can invoke with

```
\urlstyle{sf}
```

For the DOI field, `natbib` defines the command `\doi` via something like
`\providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi: #1}` which you can override with

```
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: \url{#1}}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@article{foo2010,
  author = "Foo Bar",
  journal = "J.P.B.",
  year = 2010,
  title = "Where the wild things are.",
  doi = {10.1.1/jpb001},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1.1/jpb001}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}

\usepackage{helvet}  % helvetica font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{sfmath}  % helvetica for math mode too
\urlstyle{sf}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: \url{#1}}

\begin{document}
test \citet{foo2010}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This changes the style of the url but not of the doi number. There the style inserts locally `\urlstyle{rm}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thansk I missed that - answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You could redefine the rm-urlstyle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib,hyperref}

\usepackage{helvet}  % helvetica font
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
%\usepackage{sfmath}  % helvetica for math mode too
\makeatletter
\def\url@rmstyle{%
  \def\UrlFont{\sffamily}}
 \makeatother 
\begin{document}
test \citet{foo2010}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

[image]